# Easy and free way to deploy a website made with Express (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, express

I made a small website using Express (node.js), using routes and all that stuff in my notebook. I access it writing http://localhost:3000/ on my browser (the location of my main page) and I run the server on my command line. I have all the usual stuff that appears when you create an Express app. I want to test it online though because I'm learning node.js and I want to see how it is done. I have no idea how to get it online though, I know how to do it on my computer, but no idea how to set it online or how to get it up and running.

Comment: Rent a node.js server and upload using ftp.

Comment: has to be free, I don't have money.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/nodejs). It's a PaaS (Platform as a Service), that provides a free, entry-level service to run and deploy your app on. Services like Heroku are great for testing small apps without having to worry about configuring a server environment.

Heroku runs your app in what it calls `dynos`. Think of a dyno as a pre-configured server with all the software you need to run your app, in this case you'd choose the Node.js dyno, so it would have Node, npm etc already installed.

If your app uses MongoDB, [mLab's](https://mlab.com/) free-tier provides you with a hosted 500MB Mongo database, which should be more than enough for a small app.

Comment: ok very thanks, Im checking out Heroku right now.

Comment: I do use MongDB and Im already using mLab, thanks :)

Comment: just a quick question, is deploying an app in a job enviroment much different than this? Is it something I shouldn't worry about for the time being?

Comment: @WernerGermánBusch Yeah, although Heroku does offer high-end options, the standard is to use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) for hosting and other services, as it's highly-configurable, efficient and robust.
You don't need to worry about it too much at the moment though, there's a lot moving parts in an enterprise environment that just aren't relevant for testing small apps.